# Express, How to get value from html

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've node with express and I've simple index.html file which serves like following

**app.js**

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views/index.html'));
});


app.post('/up', function(req, res){
```

....

**index.html**

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span>
            File Name: <input type="text" name="FileName"><br>
            <div class="progress">
              <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar"></div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-lg up-btn" type="button">Run App</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

when the user run the app there is input fields`file Name` which he can type value there , I want to **get the value when the user click on the button** `Run App` 
inside the post method in the `app.js`, How can I get it ?

I try with events without sucess

Comment: do you want that the user enters a file name path from his local device (laptop) ?

Comment: Since you aren't using a form, to get the value from the client side to the server side you would need to extract the value from the input, attach an event listener to the button and send this value to your server through AJAX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should have a form to your html with a button type `submit`:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span>
            <form action="up" method="POST">
              File Name: <input type="text" name="FileName"><br>
              <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar"></div>
              </div>
              <button class="btn btn-lg up-btn" type="submit">Run App</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Then on your server you need to have the `body-parser` package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Then into server side application you need this code:

```js
var express    = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(bodyParser());

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views/index.html'));
});


app.post('/up', function(req, res){
  var txt_folder_name = req.body.FileName;
  //Do other stuff
})
```

Answer (score 2):

For express you can use bodyParser() middleware and get submited fields from req.body.

```
var express    = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser());

app.post('/uploaded',function(req, res, next){
    var txt_folder_name = req.body.txtFolderName;
    //...
});
```

Comment: Now I was able to run it but `req.body.txtFolderName;` is undfiend, any idea?

Comment: @Ninawatcher Have you assigned the input value to a key of `txtFolderName`?